# One table conditional join

Tags: sql, join

Is it possible in SQL to pick data from 2 tables by join with condition and when second table not satisfies the conditions then pick null values from it?

I've done it like this:

```
select * from Achievements left join (select * from PlayerAchievements where userId = 2) as t1 on t1.achievementsId = Achievements.Id
```

But I want to know is it possible to achieve the same result without sub-query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following solution using a `LEFT JOIN`. The additional condition (`userId = 2`) is used on the mapping condition (`ON`) instead of `WHERE`. So you show all rows of the left table (`Achievements`) and only append the information of the right tables (`PlayerAchievements`) if the IDs of the achievements and the `userId` is matching.

```
SELECT *  FROM Achievements A 
    LEFT JOIN PlayerAchievements PA ON A.Id = PA.achievementsId AND PA.userId = 2
```